# tf.data.Dataset: The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the given input type

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform

I'm using **Talos** and Google colab **TPU** to run hyperparameter tuning of a **Keras** model. Note that I'm using Tensorflow 1.15.0 and Keras 2.2.4-tf.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import talos as ta
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def iris_model(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, params):

    # Specify a distributed strategy to use TPU
    resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
    tf.contrib.distribute.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
    strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)

    # Use the strategy to create and compile a Keras model
    with strategy.scope():
      model = Sequential()
      model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(4,), activation=tf.nn.relu, name="relu"))
      model.add(Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name="softmax"))
      model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.1), loss=params['losses'])

    # Convert data type to use TPU
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_val = x_val.astype('float32')

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
    dataset = dataset.cache()
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(params['batch_size'], drop_remainder=True)

    # Fit the Keras model on the dataset
    out = model.fit(dataset, batch_size=params['batch_size'], epochs=params['epochs'], validation_data=[x_val, y_val], verbose=0, steps_per_epoch=2)

    return out, model

# Load dataset
X, y = ta.templates.datasets.iris()

# Train and test set
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, shuffle=False)

# Create a hyperparameter distributions 
p = {'losses': ['logcosh'], 'batch_size': [128, 256, 384, 512, 1024], 'epochs': [10, 20]}

# Use Talos to scan the best hyperparameters of the Keras model
scan_object = ta.Scan(x_train, y_train, params=p, model=iris_model, experiment_name='test', x_val=x_val, y_val=y_val, fraction_limit=0.1)
```

After converting the train set to a Dataset using `tf.data.Dataset`, I get the following error when fitting the model with `out = model.fit`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c812209b95d0> in <module>()
      8 
      9 # Use Talos to scan the best hyperparameters of the Keras model
---> 10 scan_object = ta.Scan(x_train, y_train, params=p, model=iris_model, experiment_name='test', x_val=x_val, y_val=y_val, fraction_limit=0.1)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _validate_or_infer_batch_size(self, batch_size, steps, x)
   1813             'The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the given '
   1814             'input type. Received input: {}, batch_size: {}'.format(
-> 1815                 x, batch_size))
   1816       return
   1817 

ValueError: The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the given input type. Received input: <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((512, 4), (512, 3)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>, batch_size: 512
```

Then, if I follow those instructions and don't set the batch-size argument to `model.fit`. I get another error in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c812209b95d0> in <module>()
      8 
      9 # Use Talos to scan the best hyperparameters of the Keras model
---> 10 scan_object = ta.Scan(x_train, y_train, params=p, model=iris_model, experiment_name='test', x_val=x_val, y_val=y_val, fraction_limit=0.1)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _distribution_standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, validation_split, shuffle, epochs, allow_partial_batch)
   2307             strategy) and not drop_remainder:
   2308           dataset_size = first_x_value.shape[0]
-> 2309           if dataset_size % batch_size == 0:
   2310             drop_remainder = True
   2311 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Unfortunately, we don't deal with programming issues here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. I will migrate this post to Stack Overflow.

Comment: When you use `batch` on your DataSet object you don't need to use `batch_size` when calling `fit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue on keras distributed code.

If you take a look at

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c812209b95d0> in <module>()
      8 
      9 # Use Talos to scan the best hyperparameters of the Keras model
---> 10 scan_object = ta.Scan(x_train, y_train, params=p, model=iris_model, experiment_name='test', x_val=x_val, y_val=y_val, fraction_limit=0.1)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _distribution_standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, validation_split, shuffle, epochs, allow_partial_batch)
   2307             strategy) and not drop_remainder:
   2308           dataset_size = first_x_value.shape[0]
-> 2309           if dataset_size % batch_size == 0:
   2310             drop_remainder = True
   2311 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

you can see that the error is thrown at operation "dataset_size % batch_size" and it states "unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'NoneType'". This means that at that point the batch_size variable should have already been inferred from the Dataset object but it is still 'None'

If you take a look at the source code (you can access it from collab by clicking on the path), you will see that in the fit function

```
  def fit(self,
          model,
          x=None,
          y=None,
          batch_size=None,
          epochs=1,
          verbose=1,
          callbacks=None,
          validation_split=0.,
          validation_data=None,
          shuffle=True,
          class_weight=None,
          sample_weight=None,
          initial_epoch=0,
          steps_per_epoch=None,
          validation_steps=None,
          validation_freq=1,
          **kwargs):
    """Fit loop for Distribution Strategies."""
    dist_utils.validate_callbacks(input_callbacks=callbacks,
                                  optimizer=model.optimizer)
    dist_utils.validate_inputs(x, y)

    batch_size, steps_per_epoch = dist_utils.process_batch_and_step_size(
        model._distribution_strategy,
        x,
        batch_size,
        steps_per_epoch,
        ModeKeys.TRAIN,
        validation_split=validation_split)
    batch_size = model._validate_or_infer_batch_size(
        batch_size, steps_per_epoch, x)
    dataset = model._distribution_standardize_user_data(
```

there is a step

```
batch_size = model._validate_or_infer_batch_size(
            batch_size, steps_per_epoch, x)
```

in which the batch_size should change from 'None' (default value when not specified) to the one inferred from the Dataset object (but it doesn't, I checked by printing the variable). I think this might be related to the fact that your batch_size is in fact a list of batch_sizes. If you change the source code (you can directly edit it from collab and then click on restart runtime in order to try) to this:

```
batch_size, steps_per_epoch = dist_utils.process_batch_and_step_size(
    model._distribution_strategy,
    x,
    batch_size,
    steps_per_epoch,
    ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    validation_split=validation_split)
batch_size = model._validate_or_infer_batch_size(
    batch_size, steps_per_epoch, x)
batch_size = 128
dataset = model._distribution_standardize_user_data(
```

(see that I manually inserted the batch_size in the source code after the point at which it should have been inferred) the program runs with no error.

Maybe the fact of trying different batch_sizes for hyparameter tunning is a feature that is just not feasible with this current versions. I tried tf 2.1 and did not work either.

Comment: Here is the collab with reproduction error isolation https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19_V7heuTsU5qdOQQMIAm78H7Y_pYHaUO?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried it and got the following error: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _validate_or_infer_batch_size(self, batch_size, steps, x)
   1872       provided.
   1873     """
-> 1874     if batch_size is not None and isinstance(x, dataset_ops.DatasetV2):
   1875       raise ValueError('The `batch_size` argument must not be specified when'
   1876                        ' using dataset as an input.')

ValueError: The `batch_size` argument must not be specified when using dataset as an input.

Comment: what have you exactly tried? manually adding the batch_size inside source code? it looks (from your error) that you added it in the previous line that you should (before calling validate_or_infer[...] instead of after that)

Comment: I have tried manually adding batch_size = 128 like you said:         batch_size = self._validate_or_infer_batch_size(batch_size, steps, x)
    batch_size = 128

Comment: Your trace error arises in  "_validate_or_infer_batch_size", which is before your code change, so is independent from that. This error message means that, when it enters the _validate function, "batch_size" is already different than 'None'. Are you still passing the batch size in your collab? Have you checked the colab link I shared in the first comment?

Comment: I need authorization to open the link you shared.

Comment: I didn't pass the batch_size, I get this error: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _distribution_standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, validation_split, shuffle, epochs, allow_partial_batch)
   2388           # numbers introduce more memory usage based on the size of each
   2389           # sample.
-> 2390           ds = ds.shuffle(max(1024, batch_size * 8))
   2391         if epochs > 1:
   2392           ds = ds.repeat(epochs)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page: first, my code was just error isolation, it should not be used as a workaround (in my opinion). regarding this new trace error, could you share the change you made in the source code when you get this? It looks like for some reason it didn't catch the manual bacth_size assignment (how comes it says its value is None if you manually set it to 128 in the line before?) In addition, I changed the permissions in the link, it should work now! https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1c3WVgX8E5rhuqAhS659eAI72AGeEFJen

Comment: I followed what you mentioned in the link. I get this: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _distribution_standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, validation_split, shuffle, epochs, allow_partial_batch)
   2388           # numbers introduce more memory usage based on the size of each
   2389           # sample.
-> 2390           ds = ds.shuffle(max(1024, batch_size * 8))
   2391         if epochs > 1:
   2392           ds = ds.repeat(epochs)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: In training.py, I set batch_size manually to 128 as you said, saved and restarted runtime. There are two lines with self._validate_or_infer_batch_size you can search for them, the change I made to the source code is the following: 
    batch_size = self._validate_or_infer_batch_size(batch_size, steps, x)
    batch_size = 128

Comment: I misscopied the path that had to be changed! It was [/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py] I rechecked now and could make it work. anyway the main point was that probably this is not the best option for hyperparameter tunning...

Comment: Sorry but I still get this error: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _distribution_standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, validation_split, shuffle, epochs, allow_partial_batch)
   2388           # numbers introduce more memory usage based on the size of each
   2389           # sample.
-> 2390           ds = ds.shuffle(max(1024, batch_size * 8))
   2391         if epochs > 1:
   2392           ds = ds.repeat(epochs)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Where do you save batch_size to 128 exactly? In training.py, I set batch_size manually to 128 saved and restarted runtime. There are two lines with self._validate_or_infer_batch_size you can search for them, the change I made to the source code is the following: batch_size = self._validate_or_infer_batch_size(batch_size, steps, x) batch_size = 128

Comment: So my last comment was precisely that I wrote the wrong path, I donnot change training.py but distributed_training.py. (sorry for that again!)

Comment: Thanks, now it's working. So, as you said, trying different batch_sizes for hyparameter tunning is maybe not feasible with the current versions.